# Jquery to add style to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div like this...

```
<div class="service_circle">
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase service_circle_icon"></i>
    <h5 class="service_circle_heading">Briefcase details</h5>
    <p class="service_circle_desc">We provide professional website design</p>
</div>
```

I want to apply `style="background-color:red;"` to the `<i>` element using jQuery. I have written something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".service_circle").mouseenter(function () {
            $("this").next("i").attr("style", "background-color:red !important;");
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is not working. Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `find()` to get the child `i` element and the `css()` method instead:

```
$(this).find("i").css("background-color", 'red');
```

Also note that it is better practice to set your styling in CSS and add classes to elements. Try this:

```
.red { color: red; }
```

```js
$(this).find("i").addClass('red');
```

Comment: `$(this)` instead of `$("this")`

Comment: It works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pc2ywvxb/. Check your CSS rules to make sure it's not being overridden. Also, there's no need to shout ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the child `i` then use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.

```
$(".service_circle").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find("i").css("background-color","red");
});
```

And `this` should not be in quotes. it refers to element which invoked the event.

Comment: @Pekka, `i` is empty in your fiddle so nothing is happening see https://jsfiddle.net/wo5p8o7x/ I have just put some garbage in `i` to demonstrate

Comment: @Satpal i see i thought even if empty it still have some body on it thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

**HI now you can used to css**

`CSS` `:`[hover Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

```
.service_circle:hover i{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: But i have multiple <div> with "service_circle" class..so all the <i> inside that <div> will have the effect when i hover on the one of that <div>....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".service_circle").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("i").addClass('red');
},
    $(this).find("i").removeClass('red');
);
```

Better approach with `addClass` and `removeClass` using `hover`